# Allow members of a Facebook group to like or comment, but not post

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How do I set up a group in Facebook that only allows the members to either like or comment on a post but not create new post themselves?

I want to restrict the posting to admins only.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `http://www.facebook.com/groups/GROUPNAME/edit/` or click on the wrench button in the top right of your group's page & then click on `Edit Group`
2. In the section `Posting Permissions` (the last one), select `Only administrators can post to the group.`
3. Click `Save`

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is currently possible. There are no available settings within the Groups feature to do this.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to allow comments but not posts. It's an all-or-nothing setting for members.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to let members of a group create a post, and comment on their own post — but NOT comment on others’ posts?